# how to do lookup query in firebase?

Tags: firebase, rest-firebase

Perhaps trivial question, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

If I have a long list of  let say surnames or maybe better institution names which are usually long. How do I do lookup queries when user types first few characters?

e.g.

```
technology institute
science institute
literature seminar
techinvest
technology park
animal shelter etc..
```

simply when user start typing `tech....` I want to provide

```
technology institute
techinvest
technology park
```

as resutlt for dropdown.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? This is probably the method you're looking for: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/startat.html. Or potentially this one if you're using REST: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-queries

Comment: I figured it out meantime :) but thanks anyways